# Round up a decimal

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have a problem and i need your help!

Here is the code:

```py
kg_lemons = float(input())
kg_sugar = float(input())
water = float(input())
total_lemon_juice = kg_lemons * 980 #in mililiters need to multiply by 1000
total_lemonade = total_lemon_juice + 5 * 1000 + (0.3 * kg_sugar)
cups_made = total_lemonade / 150
money_made = cups_made * 1.20
print(f'All cups sold: {cups_made:.2f}')
print(f'Money earned: {money_made:.2f}')
```

At then end, after I print it, it must shown the numbers:

```
All cups sold: 66
Money earned: 79.20
```

But I got:

```
All cups sold: 66.01
Money earned: 79.21
```

So I need to round it up to the second decimal (the lowest number). Should I use `math.floor` and, if so, how?

Comment: Looks like you may need to review the python basics: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp

Comment: Python has rounding down division (similar to integer division) using `//`, so you can correctly calculate the maximum number of full cups of lemonade that will be produced. As for the money earned, floats don't work like you think they do:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I highly recommend using the decimal class or storing the number of **cents** made, not the number of dollars, so you store an integral amount, and then report back however much money was made in dollars by dividing only during reporting.

Comment: Thanks that rlly worked out for me !